# Show latest news article (complete) on a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, news-webpart

We have an physical infoscreen in the office and we would like to show the latest news article on this screen. My guess is that I have to create a page that always shows the latest news article. I have tried to do this by using the News Webpart, however this doesn't let me show the full article, only previews.

What is the best way to show the latest news article in full, on a page or on the infoscreen?
If this is possible to show with just pointing to the correct URL that would be even better.

Comment: I'm afraid we won't be able to display the full content of the news on the page. there's no out-of-the-box way to do this in SharePoint at the moment.